# How to download all image as JPG using Sonata Media Bundle Symfony2.3

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-media-bundle

As for now, I am able to download the images in the actual format. But I need to download all form of images only in JPG format.

**config.yml**

```
sonata_media:
default_context: default
db_driver: doctrine_orm
contexts:
    default:
        providers:
            - sonata.media.provider.image
            - sonata.media.provider.file

        formats:
            xsmall: { height: 50 , quality: 70}
            small: { width: 100 , quality: 70}
            big:   { width: 500 , quality: 70}

cdn:
    server:
        path: /uploads/media

filesystem:
    local:
        directory:  %kernel.root_dir%/../web/uploads/media
        create:     false
```

**PictureController.php**

```
public function downloadPictureAction(Picture $picture)
{
    $media = $picture->media;

    $mediaManager = $this->get('sonata.media.pool');
    $provider = $mediaManager->getProvider($media->getProviderName());
    $publicUrl = $provider->generatePublicUrl($media, 'reference');
    $webDirectory = $this->container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir').'/../web';
    $filePath = $webDirectory.$publicUrl;        

    $response = new Response();
    $response->headers->set('Cache-Control', 'private');
    $response->headers->set('Content-type', mime_content_type($filePath));
    $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="'.basename($filePath).'";');
    $response->headers->set('Content-length', filesize($filePath));
    $response->sendHeaders();        
    $response->setContent(readfile($filePath));

    return $response;
}
```

Can anyone please help me out here?

Comment: Do you want to convert your original images when they get uploaded or convert them in controller, cache and output via response?

Answer (score 0):

Replace following line in your code

```
$response->setContent(readfile($filePath));
```

to

```
$response->setContent(file_get_contents($filename));
```

let me know if face issue

Comment: I am sure your answer will work for downloading, but my requirement is to download the image only with `.jpg` format